# Error in Terminal when I open it

Tags: macos, bash, rvm

```
Last login: Wed Jun 12 15:15:00 on ttys000
-bash: Downloading: command not found
-bash: Upgrading: command not found
-bash: RVM: command not found
-bash: RVM: command not found
-bash: Upgrade: command not found
-bash: Upgrade: command not found
-bash: Downloading: command not found
-bash: Upgrading: command not found
-bash: RVM: command not found
-bash: RVM: command not found
-bash: Upgrade: command not found
-bash: Upgrade: command not found
iMac-de-Media:~ medialab$
```

Comment: Especially: what have you added to your shell startup files (.bashrc, .bash_profile, etc)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have invalid information in your .bash_profile or .bashrc file. These files need to be in bash script format. Official documentation is here: [GNU.org Bash Startup Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

You can test with this command or something very similar:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

This will allow you to pinpoint the specific file where the errors/invalid text is.